# Code not getting recognized by heroku (Node.JS) (Discord.js v12)

Tags: heroku

I'm using a command handler & it looks for the file in commands folder. I used snekfetch to fetch data in a normal file. The only problem is, it works in my computer but when I move to heroku, there is no output/no error. It's like it doesn't even read it.

I know my code isn't wrong since it's working perfectly in my computer. I'm just wondering why it isn't working in Heroku?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Instead of _describing_ your code, _show it to us_.

Comment: No problems with Procfile?

Comment: Nope, No issue at all with the Procfile. I used node worker and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. This is because snekfetch is depreciated and won't work in Heroku.